# How can I change the title color in an html page?

Tags: html, css

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="bgimg" valign="middle" width="10%" title="some title" nowrap>
            <img src="images/SomeLogo.gif"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can i format the title text ("some title") color to red?

Comment: check out [this post on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969927/changing-the-tooltip-color-for-a-hyperlink-using-html-and-css).

Comment: You could also see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider putting style information into a CSS file and linking to it your html head with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YourCSSFile.css" />
```

Then your css file could contain something like:

```
td{
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight:normal;
   color:#f7f7f7; //this is a hex value representing a light grey
}
```

Comment: this is nice, but don't answer the question. what's going on here?