# How to change the color of title attribute using css?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url(style.css);
    </style>
<body>
    
   <h1 title = "planet">Earth</h1>
   <h1 title = "planet">Venus</h1>
   <h1 title = "planet">Mars</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

when i hover over `Earth`, i get `planet`. But how do i change planet's color (title attribute ) to red using CSS?
I did some research and found a similar question on stackoverflow, ([How can I change the title color in an html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496633/how-can-i-change-the-title-color-in-an-html-page)) but i doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Why are you using `@import` in a `<style>` instead of using `<link rel="stylesheet">`?

Comment: @Dai we can use use `link` as well, but i learning how to use `@import` to get `style.css`